# CSS Text Over Picture

Tags: css

I have the problem to place some text (in my case a date) over a picture. I tried many solutions [like these](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) and that worked.

But now I want to display all of my blog-post article thumbnails as a timeline with the date written over the picture.

So one of the problems is, if I place the text over the image, then the next picture will go to the next line, and I don't want that.

So details of my page as an example:

- content width: 600px or 200px depends on the screen or device
- thumbnail: 100px * 100px

So in the case of 600px, it should be 6 pictures per row; in case of 200px should be 2 pictures per row.

Comment: Please add some code or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: For best results, post the relevant snippets of your HTML and CSS here. Bonus points for creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem. This allows us to examine your code for bugs that are not obvious from an English description, and to test out changes in real time in order to find and demonstrate the most useful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dL6np/) Below is an unordered-list of blog posts with the date on top. They are links since you call them "thumbnails" --- the css uses @media rules as breakpoints for your image gride. The .block class on the links define the width of each image because images are set to 100% width and confined only by the .block. The height of the .block is defined by the proportions of the image, so if you put in different size images, you will break the grid.

HTML

```
<ul class="time-line">

    <li><a class="block">
        <img alt="timeline image"
        src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />

        <h2>42/15/2013</h2>
    </a></li>

    <!-- repeat the list items as needed or insert a loop if you are using php or WP or something -->


</ul> <!-- .time-line -->
```

CSS

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 80em;
}

.time-line {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f06;
    color: white;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.block img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}


@media (min-width: 30em) {

    .block {
        width: 33.333333%;
    }

} /* ====================== */

@media (min-width: 40em) {

    .block {
        width: 25%;
    }

} /* ====================== */


@media (min-width: 50em) {

    .block {
        width: 20%;
    }

} /* ====================== */


@media (min-width: 60em) {

    .block {
        width: 16.666666%;
    }

} /* ====================== */
```

Comment: Verry thanx. That work. Sorry for my late answer. But i'am on travel. So i have just a view hours in the evening. I have to do some php stuff and some small changes. But thats it.

Comment: And yes next time i use that jsFiddle for some Code examples... Thanx I will post the result so you can check it out... Give me some time to implement it.

Comment: Cool. I love it when people post the outcome.

Comment: For anyone running across this in 2017, I would recommend flex-box instead of floats for this type of grid.